# Changing the margin in a custom adapter onClick callback not working, android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am displaying a `ListView` using a custom adapter. In the view i have a `textView` and a button in a layout.

What is supposed to happen -> As soon as i click on the text view the `onClick` callback in the custom adapter class for the `TextView` sets the margin for the button_layout like so

```
View button_layout = (((View)(View)v.getParent()).getParent()).findViewById(R.id.button_layout));
MarginLayoutParams margins=(MarginLayoutParams)button_layout.getLayoutParams();
margins.bottomMargin=-100;
```

But this is not happening.I am able to change the background color. But not able to change the bottom margin. The `customadapter` is a part of the larger code which i cannot disclose.

The app doesnt crash but doesnt work either. If i see in the debugger the value of bottomMargin for the layout has changed but it is not reflected in the UI :( I have put some part of the code here. assume that the onClickListener has been set. It is working because as i said i am able to change the background color of the layout on Clicking the Text View.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<someClass> implements OnClickListener{
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       }
        public void onClick(View v){
            View row_to_hide = (((View        ((View)v.getParent()).getParent()).findViewById(R.id.row_to_hide));`
            MarginLayoutParams margins=(MarginLayoutParams)row_to_hide.getLayoutParams();`
              margins.bottomMargin=-100;`
                                        }
   }
```

I am new to android and would like to know if there something conceptually wrong with this approach. Also the `textView` and the button are in a Relative layout and a Linear layout respectively.

I am trying to change the margins of the linear layout in which the button is situated so that i can hide the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed layout params but you have to set them back to view. So method `setLayoutParams` is missing there. Code shold look like this:

```
View button_layout = (((View)(View)v.getParent()).getParent()).findViewById(R.id.button_layout));
MarginLayoutParams margins=(MarginLayoutParams)button_layout.getLayoutParams();
margins.bottomMargin=-100; 
button_layout.setLayoutParams(margins);
```

**Side note:** You should replace `((View)(View)v.getParent()).getParent())` with `convertView` parameter from `getView` method.